# Angular: How to update DB with changes from input fields inside ng-repeat

Tags: php, angular, oracle, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm making a small Angular page for a personal project (a tournament). I use an Oracle DB where I store all the matches. With PHP I'm able to make a request to that DB and to receive all that matches which I store in an array (name and goals from the teams).

I use Angular (ng-repeat) to show this Array on my page. As you can see there are input fields inside each row, to fill in how many goals each team scores. Now when you click the button on the bottom (see picture), I want to update all the rows in the DB (through PHP).

What is the easiest way to do this? How can I change that array with the new values from the input fields and send them to DB?

HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="wedstrijd in ophalen track by $index">
  <td class="ploeg">{{wedstrijd.ploeg1_naam}}</td>
  <td class="doelpunten"><input type="text" value={{wedstrijd.ploeg1_doelpunten}}></td>
  <td class="streepje">-</td>
  <td class="doelpunten"><input type="text" value={{wedstrijd.ploeg2_doelpunten}}></td>
  <td class="ploeg">{{wedstrijd.ploeg2_naam}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Screen from my page:

[image: Matches]

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways possible, by instance

**Solution 1**

- Get all array with updated value by interface
- Send it all to back end

**Solution 2**

- Get all array with updated value by interface
- Send it one by one to back end

> **First steps are common**

**Step 1**
In Angular template, change value="..." by [(ngModel)]="..."
Double data binding will update direclty your array (ophalen)

```
...
<td class="doelpunten"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="wedstrijd.ploeg1_doelpunten"></td>
...
```

**Step 2**
In Angular controller, send your array into with a http data of you array (ophalen)

```
constructor(...
            private updateService: UpdateService
            ...
}

// Called on button 'Updaten'
onSubmit() {
    ...
    // Save
    this.updateService.save(this.ophalen).subscribe(
        (result: any) => {
            // Do something like echo message
        }
    );
}
```

**Step 3**
Create a Angular service to call your backend (PHP). Here you can choose to go one by one or all at once. Service will get your array as input parameter anyway.

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export class UpdateService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    saveAll(arrayModel: any): Observable<any> {
       const url = 'url/to/your/php/post/service';
       return this.http.post<any[]>(url, arrayModel);
       // Or loop on each and call saveOne...
    }

    saveOne(model: any): Observable<any> {
       const url = 'url/to/your/php/post/service';
       // with full model
       return this.http.post<any[]>(url, model);
       // or only with ids and new value
       return this.http.post<any[]>(url, {id:model.id, newValue:model.ploeg1_doelpunten);
    }

}
```

**Step 4**
In PHP, you have to create one/multiple rest entry point(s).

- Parsing JSON and looping on it in PHP should not be a problem to generate needed SQL update statement.
- If you go one by one, it's same SQL generation. Only you don't need to loop obviously.